# Sending a whatsapp message from app

Tags: android

is there a way in android to send a whatsapp message straight from my own app?
I want the user to select a whatsapp contact and then have my app send the whatsapp message

Thanks

Comment: Why would you want to do this? Arent there enough 'multiple IM' applications out there?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to send an "Intent" to whatsapp, like GoogleMap sharing an location

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible.

WhatsApp is a third party service, and you cannot make it send a message. At best, you can use a share intent which will create a chooser from which the user may select WhatsApp. This does not guarantee that the message will be sent, but it is the best you can do.